# Storing String value into the field of JSON type

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-types

There is an entity for Events:

```
@Entity
class Event {
    private Long id;
    private String eventName;
    private String eventData; // json value of object eg. Invoice, Payment.
}
```

When I tried to insert a new record, PostgreSSQL is giving an error because type of `eventData` field is json. I cannot use a specific type for eventData to convert to Json object because it can be any event (Invoice, Payment etc). Is there any way to convert to Generic type.

I've used Hibernate-types-52 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implementation should work (for PostgreSQL `JsonBinaryType.class` should be used for both `"json"` and `"jsonb"` columns types [according to Vlad Minalcea's statement](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/)):

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String eventName;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String eventData;
// getters/setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to get into some hacks and workarounds you can do something like:

```
class EventData {
    Invoice invoice;
    Payment payment;
    // ... etc for all types of data you wish to store in an event.     
}
```

Then your `Event` entity looks like:

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
})
@Entity
class Event {
    private Long id;
    private String eventName;

    @Type(type = "json")
    private EventData eventData;
}
```

Just populate the right EventData property, and let `hibernate-types-52` do the conversion as they advertise.